# nested type in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have a templated class Foo, of which I want to typedef smart pointers.

AFAIK I can't typedef this outside the class. The code below (or variants of it) won't work.

```
template<typename T>
typedef shared_ptr< Foo<T> > Foo_Ptr<T>;
```

So I have typedefed shared_ptr and weak_ptr inside the class.

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    typedef shared_ptr< Foo<T> > Ptr;
    typedef weak_ptr< Foo<T> > WeakPtr;
};
```

Which is annoying because I can't forward declare it now in other headers.

But my question is, whenever I want to declare a Foo::Ptr I have to precede it with typename. e.g.

```
template<typename T>
class Bar {
   void do(typename Foo<T>::Ptr p);
}
```

This syntax is a bit cumbersome, it's actually quicker to write `shared_ptr<Foo<T>>`

Is there any alternatives? I.e. a way of declaring Foo::Ptr (or even Foo::Ptr) in any context which is templated to T? (e.g. inside the class Bar?)

---

EDIT.

Based on Denis's answer, I'm thinking of going with this

types.h

```
template<typename T>
class Foo;

template<typename T>
using Foo_Ptr = std::shared_ptr< Foo<T> >;

template<typename T>
class Bar;

template<typename T>
using Bar_Ptr = std::shared_ptr< Bar<T> >;
```

Foo.h

```
#include "types.h"
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:

};
```

elsewhere

```
#include "Foo.h"

template<typename T>
void do_sth(Foo_Ptr<T> p) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce an alias with `using` like the stdlib does it for type_traits ([like `std_enable_if_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)), which doesn't require the typename keyword:

```
using foo_ptr_t = typename Node<T>::Ptr;
```

A possible example is:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename>
struct Foo { };

template<typename T>
class Node {
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo<T>> Ptr;
    typedef std::weak_ptr<Foo<T>> WeakPtr;
};

template<typename T>
using foo_ptr_t = typename Node<T>::Ptr;

void do_sth(foo_ptr_t<int> p) { }
```

**[Demo](https://goo.gl/YBcYpZ)**

Comment: oh that's great thanks. I wasn't aware of this 'using' alias syntax. From what I've read it's a superset of typedef, and I can use it with templates? So I could remove the shared_ptr typedefs from inside the class and have them all outside? I'll update my question with proposed code (it compiles in the compiler explorer)